# Zooming to first queried feature using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I'm attempting to query a feature class for all features that meet a certain criterion (in this case, the `Status` field is `NULL`). However, I'm not getting very far into the attempted method before ArcMap crashes completely. I have no reasonable idea on how to trace errors that cause a program crash, for starters, so I'm more confused than necessary, I expect. I'm building this in VS 2008 Express, for what it's worth.

```
 public void PerformAttributeQuery(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass fc)
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter queryFilter = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilterClass();
        queryFilter.WhereClause = "[Status] IS NULL"; // create the where clause statement
```

Everything is fine for that first couple of statements, but this query causes a crash:

```
        // query the table passed into the function and use a cursor to hold the results
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor featurecursor = fc.Search(queryFilter, false);
```

It crashes before reaching the next line (I put in debug message boxes for testing), but I'll put it here for propriety:

```
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature feature = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature)featurecursor.NextFeature();
        ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IContentsView currentContentsView = ArcMap.Document.CurrentContentsView as IContentsView;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)currentContentsView.SelectedItem;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureSelection fSelection = featureLayer as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureSelection;
        fSelection.Add(feature);
        FindCommandAndExecute(ArcMap.Application as ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication, "{AB073B49-DE5E-11D1-AA80-00C04FA37860}");
    }
```

I cannibalized the `PerformAttributeQuery` [snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000008r000000) to work with FeatureClasses instead of Tables (or so I had hoped), if you'd like a proper reference. My questions are:

1. How can I get better reporting of crash errors?
2. Where did I go wrong? **Answer**: I must shamefacedly admit that I used the wrong characters to denote the location of the feature table I was querying. Changing the `[Status]` in my `queryFilter.WhereClause` to `\"Status\"` quite literally solved all obvious problems.

Comment: +1 As a non-user of arcobjects I can only sit by and wait for good answers, but I admire how well this question has been thought out and presented: it provides necessary information, it relates what steps you have taken to a solution, it minimizes the code it needs to quote (but doesn't hesitate to show code), it provides a link to an authoritative reference, and it asks clear, constructive, pointed questions.  I hope it gets lots of upvotes for those reasons alone--and of course I trust it will get more useful responses than this one!

Comment: Does the status field really exist?  Are you really using access? The square bracket delimiters are only for access, according to [the doc](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/WhereClause_Property/0025000006n5000000/).

Comment: Also, to get better reporting, use [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and in the catch block recurse into Exception.InnerException.

Comment: Yes, this method is only called after a field check method returns with proof of the `Status` field existing. However, I will try with the adjusted bracket types to quotes. Could you please explain a bit more about what you mean with `Exception.InnerException`? Might as well put it up as an answer so I can give it due credit and reputation, yes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see code below

Note that sometimes useful exception messages can be embedded inside of a fairly cryptic general message, so it is important to examine InnerExceptions.

```
protected override void OnClick()
{
    string path = @"C:\projects\NetTools\InfrastructureEditingTemplate\MapsandGeodatabase\LocalGovernment.gdb";
    try
    {
        var ws = Open(path);
        var fc = ((IFeatureWorkspace)ws).OpenFeatureClass("wMain");
        IFeature feat = QueryFirstFeature(fc);
        if (feat != null)
        {
            //todo: project if necessary
            ((IActiveView)ArcMap.Document.FocusMap).Extent = feat.Shape.Envelope;
            ((IActiveView)ArcMap.Document.FocusMap).Refresh();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        while (ex != null)
        {
            Debug.Print("{0} \n {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}

private IFeature QueryFirstFeature(IFeatureClass fc)
{
    IFeature outFeat = null;
    IQueryFilter qf = new QueryFilterClass();
    qf.WhereClause = "LASTEDITOR = 'ESRI'";
    IFeatureCursor fCur = null;
    try
    {
        fCur = fc.Search(qf, false);
        outFeat = fCur.NextFeature();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var ex2 = new Exception("Exception when querying with " + qf.WhereClause, ex);
        throw ex2;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(fCur != null)
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(fCur);
    }
    return outFeat;
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of FinalReleaseComObject instead of ReleaseComObject. I wondered what the the difference was and came upon this answer which explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827059/why-use-finalreleasecomobject-instead-of-releasecomobject/1827835#1827835

Comment: Is there any specific reason use of the Zoom to Selected Features command sets the zoom scale to `1:4.189069e+017`?

Comment: Are you trying to zoom to a point?  If so, I'd add a bit of code that calls IEnvelope.Expand first.